# CASE WHEN not working with email

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

the sql query below works great for all of the checks in the CASE WHEN, accept for some of the emails. When every i run the query checking for an email it works sometimes and sometimes it does not. I've done a RTRIM(LTRIM(m.Email)) and this does not work either.
Is there something i need to do different when comparing emails?

```
exec BuildingPros.uspGetEmployees 1697,'Email','someone@somewhere.net'


alter proc BuildingPros.uspGetEmployees
@ProID INT,
@Where  VARCHAR(12) = NULL,
@Equals VARCHAR(25) = NULL
AS
      SELECT m.UserId,u.UserName,e.NonProID'ID',m.Email,c.FirstName'FName',c.LastName'LName',
                      ISNULL(c.Title,'NA')'Title',z.ZIPCode'Zip', p.Phone
        FROM     Person.UtbAddressesutbContact ac JOIN
                          Person.utbAddresses a ON ac.AddressID = a.AddressID JOIN 
                          Person.utbContact c ON ac.ContactID = c.ContactID JOIN
                          Person.utbZipCodes z ON z.ZipCodeID = a.ZipCodeID JOIN
                          Person.utbCitys city ON city.CityID = z.CityID JOIN
                          Person.utbContactUtbPhones cp ON c.ContactID = cp.ContactID JOIN
                          Person.utbPhones p ON p.PhoneID = cp.PhonesID JOIN
                          NonPros.utbNonProsUtbAddresses ea ON a.AddressID = ea.AddressID JOIN
                          aspnet_Membership m JOIN
                          NonPros.NonPros e ON m.UserId = e.UserID ON ea.NonProID = e.NonProID JOIN
                          BuildingPros.utbProfessionalsUtbNonPros pe ON e.NonProID = pe.NonProID JOIN
                          dbo.aspnet_Users u ON u.UserId = m.UserId
                WHERE
                CASE @Where
                        WHEN 'Email'    THEN m.Email
                        WHEN 'Name'     THEN c.LastName             
                        WHEN 'Zip'      THEN z.ZIPCode
                        WHEN 'ST'       THEN z.StateCD
                        WHEN 'Title'    THEN c.Title
                        WHEN 'TimeZone' THEN z.TimeZone
                        WHEN 'City'     THEN city.City
                END = @Equals
```

Comment: It looks like the join on `aspnet_Membership` is cut and pasted strangely wrt to its `on` clause.  That is where the email address comes from.

Comment: I would just make the point that using a CASE like this in a WHERE clause will mean that you the optimizer will not be able to build an efficient plan utilising indexes, I suspect that you will end up with a table scan regardless of the inputs. You would be better to either separate the queries into 7 queries using WHERE m.Email = @Equals etc. Which sub-query gets run can be determined by an IF clause. If you want to tidy it up further you could have eachs ub query ina sub-stored procedure.

Comment: You can also use Like operator for string comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suspect that it works for those emails that are shorter than 26 characters in length and that is fails on emails that are 26 characters or more in length. `VARCHAR(25)` is insufficient for an email address.

Comment: When I woke up this morning that was the fist thing I thought about. Goes to show what happens when I get caught up in the code. Thank you.